# Find the coefficient of Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

What is the coefficient of $x^n$ for the Taylor series $(1+x)^p$? What is the interval of convergence (R)?

I can write the Taylor series as-
$$f(x) = 1+px+\frac{p(p-1)}{2!}x^2 +\frac{p(p-1)(p-2)}{3!}x^3 +... $$
But I can't find the general formula $(a_n)$ for the coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Hint: Binomial coefficient.

Comment: I tried the formula $a_n=\frac{p!}{n!(p-n)!}$ but it does not produce correct answer when $n=p+1$. For example, when $p=2$ and $n=3$, the formula gives $-\frac13$ while the coefficient is $a_3=0$.

Comment: The Taylor series in this case is a polynomial of degree $p$.  $\binom{p}{n}=0 \text{ for } n >p.$  Also, $(-1)! \ne -1$

Comment: That's where I got confused. So n>p terms are undefined for that particular Taylor series?

Answer (score 1):

We recall the *[Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)* of $f$ around $x=0$ is given as
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We assume $p$ is a non-negative integer. In this case the function $f(x)=(1+x)^p$ can be written according to the binomial theorem as
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=(1+x)^p=\sum_{n=0}^p\binom{p}{n}x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{p}\frac{p!}{(p-n)!n!}x^n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparison of (1) and (2) shows that (2) *is* already the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^p$ around $x=0$ with coefficients
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\begin{cases}
> \binom{p}{n}&0\leq n\leq p\\
> 0&n>p
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>   Since $(1+x)^p$ is a polynomial of degree $p$ it converges for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so $R=\infty$.

*Hint:* The more general framework of *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and especially the *[regions of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Conditions_for_convergence)* might be interesting.